# window.print() displays my content differently in 3 different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to adjust a set of divs to fit the "Avery" business-card printer paper. What this thing does it allows the user to print out the content of a dynamic number of divs (as business-card shaped) unto a specific type of paper to easily separate the pieces post-printing.

My problem is that every browser displays the "window.print()" content differently. If I try to set up the divs to fit the printer-paper under Chrome (for example) it won't work well if the user prints the same document from Opera or Firefox.

I tried three browsers so far (Opera, Firefox and Chrome), and each one of them displays the content slightly differently. The problem with this is that I can't control which browser the end-users will utilize when printing.

Is there a way to create a file that is read equally from any browser? I know the pdf is suppose to do that, but is there a way to dynamically generate a pdf in js or jquery?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Does the page you are printing look good in all the browsers?

Comment: Do you have any print css?

Comment: Print support is absolutely abysmal in all modern browsers. You can try using `@media print {} ` style sheets, but there's only so much you can rely on.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. The pages don't look good. @Pointy I am using media print {} to hide my body and to enable the visibility on certain divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jsPDF

http://jquer.in/random-jquery-plugins-for-superior-websites/jspdf/

See live example:

http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: Allyson thank you for your answer. It would seem this plugin may be able to help.